# `min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded` error on `flatpak update`

Tags: 18.04, flatpak

Any ideas why `flatpak update` fails? I have plenty of free space really.

```
$ flatpak update 
Looking for updates...
Required runtime for org.inkscape.Inkscape/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
Installing in system:
org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale/x86_64/18.08         flathub 8d2c256bc426
org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/1.6      flathub 82006efc71d3
org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6           flathub d757f762489e
org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.28                flathub 2823e3d81b74
org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.30                flathub d3ff07ad7633
org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/18.08    flathub bc9426ac6a1c
org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs/x86_64/18.08   flathub 3e019185d277
org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34                       flathub ab1f439a6e9e
org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.34                flathub e20da7a61852
org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/19.08     flathub 250415c36700
org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-430-50/x86_64/1.4 flathub f88e0a854047
org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Ambiance/x86_64/3.22               flathub 73fed99df212
org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/19.08    flathub 8db05639a302
org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08       flathub 563e6c1a7173
Updating in system:
org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08          flathub 4cf11470343e
org.audacityteam.Audacity.Codecs/x86_64/stable flathub 2936bff19b0d
org.audacityteam.Audacity.Locale/x86_64/stable flathub ab86e963d75f
net.sourceforge.xournal/x86_64/stable          flathub e25def6b0359
net.sourceforge.xournal.Locale/x86_64/stable   flathub 0a53eaa252ad
org.inkscape.Inkscape/x86_64/stable            flathub 351ad9649e37
org.inkscape.Inkscape.Locale/x86_64/stable     flathub 65939c95a615
Is this ok [y/n]: y
Updating: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08 from flathub
Error: Failed to update org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale/x86_64/18.08 due to previous error
Updating: org.audacityteam.Audacity.Codecs/x86_64/stable from flathub
Warning: Failed to update org.audacityteam.Audacity.Codecs/x86_64/stable: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Updating: org.audacityteam.Audacity.Locale/x86_64/stable from flathub
Warning: Failed to update org.audacityteam.Audacity.Locale/x86_64/stable: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Updating: net.sourceforge.xournal/x86_64/stable from flathub
Error: Failed to update net.sourceforge.xournal/x86_64/stable: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Skipping net.sourceforge.xournal.Locale/x86_64/stable due to previous error
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/1.6 from flathub
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/1.6: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6 from flathub
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Installing: org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.28 from flathub
Warning: Failed to install org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.28: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Installing: org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.30 from flathub
Warning: Failed to install org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.30: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/18.08 due to previous error
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs/x86_64/18.08 due to previous error
Installing: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34 from flathub
Error: Failed to install org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34: min-free-space-size 500MB would be exceeded
Skipping org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.34 due to previous error
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/19.08 due to previous error
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-430-50/x86_64/1.4 due to previous error
Skipping org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Ambiance/x86_64/3.22 due to previous error
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/19.08 due to previous error
Skipping org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08 due to previous error
Skipping org.inkscape.Inkscape/x86_64/stable due to previous error
Skipping org.inkscape.Inkscape.Locale/x86_64/stable due to previous error
error: There were one or more errors
```

FYI somebody [here](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/solved-flatpak-update-says-min-free-space-size-500mb-would-be-exceeded/1922) had a seemingly the same issue and allegedly solved it himself, only I don't understand how exactly he managed to do that:

> Indeed a plain ENOSPC; I just missed the root mount in `pydf` output. After cleaning up enough space, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo flatpak update` and you'll be fine.